# production - What is the best way to load a file for fast computation?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deployment, deep-learning

I'm deploying a deep learning model and saved the *keras* model as *.h5* file. I think complex model will make it big in size and hence slow interaction at the server, but is there a way other than reducing the layers in the model that I can do? Is there a sort of compressing the *.h5* file in order to load it faster for the server?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do that.

What you are looking for is called `quantization`.

Not necessarily reducing the layers which is equivalent to model-pruning, `quantization` reduces both the size and the latency of the model by modifying the precision of the weights (or even activations in some cases).

For more detailed information, read this page on the official TensorFlow documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization